# Iteratively Load Files from List and Save to Separate DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to iteratively read several csv files from a list into pandas and load them into their separate and respective dataframes. I have not been able to figure it out yet. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

```
file_list = [
'calendar.csv'
,'sales_train_validation.csv'
,'sample_submission.csv'
,'sell_prices.csv'
]
```

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        '''init data class'''
        self.data = None

# Function to read file basename
    def file_basename_reader(file_name):
        basename = file_name.split('.')[0]
        return basename

# Function to read file extension
    def file_ext_reader(file_name):
        ext = file_name.split('.')[-1]
        return ext

# Function to load file
    def load_file(file_name):
        '''loads data from excel, csv, or txt file'''
        if Data.file_ext_reader(file_name) in ['xls','xlsx','xlsm','xlb']:
            return pd.read_excel(file_name)
        elif Data.file_ext_reader(file_name) == 'csv':
            return pd.read_csv(file_name)
        elif Data.file_ext_reader(file_name) == 'txt':
            return pd.read_table(file_name)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid file format. Please check file extension to be excel, csv, or txt.')

# Function to read list of file names and iteratively create data frames
    def create_dataframe(file_list):
        global df
        global data_df
        df = ['calendar_df','sales_train_validation_df','sample_submission_df','sell_prices_df']
        for file in range(len(file_list)):
            df = Data.load_file(file_list[file])
```

```
Data.create_dataframe(file_list)
```

When I run Data.create_dataframe(file_list) , I was hoping to get 4 dataframes ('calendar_df','sales_train_validation_df','sample_submission_df','sell_prices_df').  When I read the .head() nothing is returned for these 4 dataframes.  The only that return is for df.head(). What fix should I apply to the create_dataframe(file_list) function?

Comment: You seem to know how lists and return statements work, so what's with the weird global variable design of `create_dataframe`? The first problem I can notice is that you override `df` in every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Neither df nor data_df needs to be a global - df Is defined and used locally and data_df doesn't seem to exist anywhere. Can you clarify what you want your output to be? Are you looking for a list of dataframes? I'd suggest simplifying your problem so you can really figure out what is working the way you expect and what isn't. For example, these don't appear to need to be part of a class... It just complicates the code.

Comment: Also, why are you using a class? It does not seem to have any state (the `data` attribute is not used) and you don't instantiate it.

Comment: So I am trying to iteratively load the csv files into separate dataframes and then assign each a name from the list ('calendar_df','sales_train_validation_df','sample_submission_df','sell_prices_df').  Later,  I would like to be able to call the dataframes in my code for further analysis. For example, "calendar.df.head()".  I just tried global hoping that it would provide me with the outcome I was hoping for but that did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `df`: you keep overriding it when you read new dataframes.

One way to solve it as the following. At the top of the class, define a list of dataframes:

```
class Data:
    dataframes = {}
```

Then in `create_dataframe`, do the following:

```
def create_dataframe(file_list):

    for file in range(len(file_list)):
        df = Data.load_file(file_list[file])   
        Data.dataframes.append(df)
```

The result will be four dataframes in the `Data.dataframes` variable. If you'd rather use a duct rather than a list, you can obviously do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion for cleaner code that returns a list of dataframes. Let me know if this works for you.

```
import os

# define readers for expected extensions
excel = ['.xls','.xlsx','.xlsm','.xlb']
readers = {ext: pd.read_excel for ext in _excel}
readers.update({'.csv': pd.read_csv, '.txt': pd.read_table})

# function to apply correct reader to list of files
def read_files(file_list, readers):
    return [readers[os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower()](f) for f in file_list]

# call read_files with a file list and a readers dictionary
# ...
```

If needed, this function could be extended to use different additional arguments for reading each file.

Comment: I really like how the code is clean.  The one thing that I would like to happen is to have each of the file read in and stored into their respective dataframes for later use.

Comment: @user13624923 This is exactly what the code does when you call `dataframes = read_files(['calendar.csv','sales_train_validation.csv','sample_submission.csv','sell_prices.csv'], readers)`.

Comment: @user13624923 No problem. Feel free to accept an answer if the problem is solved.